# What does LPCWSTR stand for and how should it be handled?

Tags: c++, winapi, lpcstr

First of all, what is it exactly? I guess it is a pointer (LPC means long pointer constant), but what does "W" mean? Is it a specific pointer to a string or a pointer to a specific string?
 For example I want to close a Window named "TestWindow".

```
HWND g_hTest;
LPCWSTR a;
*a = ("TestWindow");
g_hTest = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, a);
DestroyWindow(g_hTest);
```

The code is illegal and it doesn't work since const char[6] cannot be converted to CONST WCHAR.
I don't get it at all. 
I want to get a clear understanding of all these LPCWSTR, LPCSTR, LPSTR. I tried to find something , however I got confused even more. At msdn site `FindWindowEx` is declared as

```
HWND FindWindowEx(      
    HWND hwndParent,
    HWND hwndChildAfter,
    LPCTSTR lpszClass,
    LPCTSTR lpszWindow
);
```

So the last parameter is LPCSTR, and the compiler demands on LPCWSTR. 
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Microsoft Hungarian notation.

Comment: it actually makes for far more readable documentation, pity everything else about it sux.

Comment: @Thomas: This is **not** what Microsoft (or Simonyi for that matter) initially tagged *Hungarian Notation*. It's more or less the result of an accident, when the documentation group decided to exercise some "readability" improvements. They weren't developers and consequently the changes weren't graceful. Background information is available at [Hugarian notation - it's my turn now :)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/22/162629.aspx)

Comment: @IInspectable: Broken link

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Yes, unfortunately. It doesn't seem to have been moved to the blog's new home, and may be gone for good.

Comment: @IInspectable: Working link is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/06/22/hugarian-notation-its-my-turn-now/

Comment: @JuliusBullinger: Thank you. I was specifically referring to [this comment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/06/22/hugarian-notation-its-my-turn-now/#comment-7981) on the blog entry.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`LPCWSTR` stands for "Long Pointer to Constant Wide String". The W stands for Wide and means that the string is stored in a 2 byte character vs. the normal `char`.  Common for any C/C++ code that has to deal with non-ASCII only strings.

To get a normal C literal string to assign to a `LPCWSTR`, you need to prefix it with `L`:

```
LPCWSTR a = L"TestWindow";
```

Comment: Just to expand - the 'LONG' part is a hangover from 16bit windows and can be ignored (excpet you need it in the name)

Comment: "hangover from 16bit Windows" -- That's for sure!

Comment: So the Hungarian Notation lies.  Microsoft must go through all their API and source code and correct all of the names.  This is why I don't use Hungarian Notation!

Comment: Nope, it's correct. It was and is a 32 bits pointer. There are no "short" 16 bits pointers anymore, so you could complain if you manage to find a `SPCWSTR`.

Comment: More like - the "L" is simply unnecessary - it should be just PCWSTR, as a pointer is always (and has been always) 32 bits.  The question is, why did they put L on in the first place? My guess is just convention that "everything must have a size designator". Which is what I don't like about Hungarian - in well-written code, if you NEED to know the type of a variable when reading an algorithm, it should be in the name (ie WindowPtr, windowHandle, shortCharHandle, WideCharConstDontEverEdit, etc).

Comment: My God.   L???  The letter L?  Not even a function, L()?  Just plain L?  Who the heck came up with that??

Comment: @user396483 It's common in many languages to add prefixes and suffixes to constants to change how they are represented, without changing their meaning to a human.  For example, `36UL` in C# is the same as `(ulong)36` (ulong being an unsigned 64-bit integer).  `@` can be used in the same language as a prefix for strings, changing how they are parsed slightly.

Comment: At least VS friends should warn of the need for the leading `L`, not even a quick fix suggestion...

Comment: @Thomas: Risking a guess I'd say, that you haven't understood (Apps) Hungarian Notation. Do yourself a favor and download a copy of the Word 1.1a source code, to see Hungarian Notation used by developers in the know.

Comment: @IInspectable:  I have already studied Hungarian Notation.  One of my big peeves is that nobody updates the notation when the variable's type changes.  I prefer to leave the variable's type out of the name.  You should download and read all the articles against Hungarian Notation.  Also, remember, Microsoft does not set the standards; they only spread many copies. And from the articles on Hungarian Notation, MS doesn't follow it completely.

Comment: @Thomas: The ultimate goal of Hungarian Notation is [Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). Apps Hungarian Notation has **nothing** to do with encoding the concrete data type. It helps to disambiguate between a `RECT` storing screen or client coordinates, an `int` representing logical or device pixels, a buffer size argument being in characters (`cch`) or bytes (`cb`), or a `char*` pointing to an ASCII or UTF-8-encoded string. If you can find an article with a single valid argument against **Apps** HN, bring it on. I won't hold my breath, though.

Comment: The L is ridiculous, What if you need to convert a variable to a LPCWSTR?!! Why does Microsoft have such insane viewpoints?!

Comment: @MehdiIjadnazar: As silly as UTF-16 is, none of this is Microsoft’s fault: they adopted UCS-2 before it was understood that it wouldn’t work, and the `L` is defined by the language since at least C89.  It works on literals only because it changes how they are interpreted: converting a “variable” involves runtime computation and buffer usage/allocation, so it can’t use so minimal a syntax.

Answer (score 17):

`LPCWSTR` is equivalent to `const wchar_t *`. It's a pointer to a wide character string that won't be modified by the function call.

You can assign a string literal to `LPCWSTR` by prepending the literal with the `L` prefix, eg:

`LPCWSTR myStr = L"Hello World";`

LPC**T**STR and any other **T** types, take a string type depending on the Unicode settings for your project. If `UNICODE` is defined for your project, the use of T types is the same as the wide (Unicode) character forms, otherwise the narrow (Ansi) character forms. The appropriate API functions will also be called this way, eg:

`FindWindowEx` is defined as `FindWindowExA` or `FindWindowExW` depending on this definition.

Comment: How do I check if I'm using correct unicode settings on a fresh install of VS and on a fresh console app project? My Farsi characters are showing as '?' question marks even though the problem is not from the command prompt, other apps print Farsi characters just fine.

Answer (score 7):

It's a long pointer to a constant, wide string (i.e. a string of wide characters).

Since it's a wide string, you want to make your constant look like: `L"TestWindow"`.

I wouldn't create the intermediate `a` either, I'd just pass `L"TestWindow"` for the parameter:

```
ghTest = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, L"TestWindow");
```

If you want to be pedantically correct, an "LPCTSTR" is a "text" string -- a wide string in a Unicode build and a narrow string in an ANSI build, so you should use the appropriate macro:

```
ghTest = FindWindow(NULL, NULL, NULL, _T("TestWindow"));
```

Few people care about producing code that can compile for both Unicode and ANSI character sets though, and if you don't then getting it to really work correctly can be quite a bit of extra work for little gain. In this particular case, there's not much extra work, but if you're manipulating strings, there's a whole set of string manipulation macros that resolve to the correct functions.

Comment: you don't need to be pedantically correct, use _T() if you're using constants like _T(MAIN_WINDOW) otherwise LMAIN_WINDOW will fail.

Comment: @JerryCoffin "*If you want to be pedantically correct ... you should use the appropriate macro*" - which would be `TEXT()` in this case, not `_T()`.  `UNICODE`, `TCHAR`, `LPCTSTR`, `TEXT()`, etc come from the Win32 API, whereas `_UNICODE`, `_TCHAR`, `_T()`, etc come from the C runtime library instead. Even though they are *mostly* interchangable, you should use the appropriate types/macros for the API you are using.

Comment: @Rodolfo you can't use `_T()` (or `TEXT()`) with declared constants, only with string/character literals directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If I ever decide to write a Win32 program that doesn't use the standard library, I might try to keep that in mind. Doesn't seem very likely to happen though...