# how to convert from LPCSTR to LPCWSTR in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

additional info
im building an application which use the WinHttpOpenRequest Api which requires LPCWSTR for the object name 
and im using visual studio 2008

Comment: Why aren't you using wide char strings throughout your app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does LPCWSTR stand for and how should it be handled with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230758/what-does-lpcwstr-stand-for-and-how-should-it-be-handled-with)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way is to use ATL:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    USES_CONVERSION;
    LPCSTR a = "hello";
    LPCWSTR w = A2W(a);
    std::wcout << w << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any memory allocated by A2W (ANSI to Wide) will be freed when the function exits.

Comment: Those ATL 3.0 macros have been superseded by version 7.0 [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) more than a decade ago. Among others, the ATL 7.0 macros no longer require the use of the `USES_CONVERSION` macro. Plus, you can use the const-correct variants, e.g. in your example: `CA2W(a)`.

Comment: However, in present 2021, there doesn't seem to be `ATL` library anymore. Any other ideas?

Comment: @IneoSenigupta - I haven't been actively involved in Windows/C++ work in a long time but, as far as I can tell ATL is in VS2019. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/active-template-library-atl-concepts?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 4):

[Converting from char *](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has a nice sample

```
char *orig = "Hello, World!";
cout << orig << " (char *)" << endl;

// Convert to a wchar_t*
size_t origsize = strlen(orig) + 1;
const size_t newsize = 100;
size_t convertedChars = 0;
wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, orig, _TRUNCATE);
wcscat_s(wcstring, L" (wchar_t *)");
wcout << wcstring << endl;
```

But like tenfour mentioned. Use [generic text mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if possible