# Error C2664: 'auxDIBImageLoadW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I was just modifying the code after reinstalling windows and VS 2012 Ultimate. The code (shown below) works perfectly fine before, but when I try to run the code right now, it gives following errors:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'auxDIBImageLoadW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Code:

```
void CreateTexture(GLuint textureArray[], LPSTR strFileName, int textureID)
{
    AUX_RGBImageRec *pBitmap = NULL;
    if (!strFileName)                                   // Return from the function if no file name was passed in
        return;
    pBitmap = auxDIBImageLoad(strFileName);     //<-Error in this line      // Load the bitmap and store the data

    if (pBitmap == NULL)                                    // If we can't load the file, quit!
        exit(0);

    // Generate a texture with the associative texture ID stored in the array
    glGenTextures(1, &textureArray[textureID]);

    // This sets the alignment requirements for the start of each pixel row in memory.
    //  glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Bind the texture to the texture arrays index and init the texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureArray[textureID]);

    // Build Mipmaps (builds different versions of the picture for distances - looks better)
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, pBitmap->sizeX, pBitmap->sizeY, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBitmap->data);

    // Lastly, we need to tell OpenGL the quality of our texture map.  GL_LINEAR is the smoothest.
    // GL_NEAREST is faster than GL_LINEAR, but looks blochy and pixelated.  Good for slower computers though.
    // Read more about the MIN and MAG filters at the bottom of main.cpp

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    //  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);


    // Now we need to free the bitmap data that we loaded since openGL stored it as a texture

    if (pBitmap)                                        // If we loaded the bitmap
    {
        if (pBitmap->data)                              // If there is texture data
        {
            free(pBitmap->data);                        // Free the texture data, we don't need it anymore
        }

        free(pBitmap);                                  // Free the bitmap structure
    }
}
```

I tried this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044506/how-to-convert-from-lpcstr-to-lpcwstr-in-c), [This one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924926/cannot-convert-parameter-1-from-char-to-lpcwstr) and also Tried [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/game-programming/76871-loading-bitmap-without-using-glaux.html) one too. but still getting error.

This function is used after initialization as:

```
LPCWSTR k =L"grass.bmp";
CreateTexture(g_Texture, "building1.bmp", 0);
CreateTexture(g_Texture, "clock.bmp", 0);
//list goes on
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a narrow string into a wide function?

Answer (score 1):

Change "LPSTR strFileName" to "LPCWSTR strFileName", "building1.bmp" to L"building1.bmp and "clock.bmp" to L"clock.bmp".

Always be careful because LPSTR is ASCII and LPCWSTR is Unicode. So if the function needs a Unicode variable (like this: L"String here") you can't give it a ASCII string.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions are either:

**Change your function prototype to take wide strings:**

```
void CreateTexture(GLuint textureArray[], LPWSTR strFileName, int textureID)
//...
LPCWSTR k =L"grass.bmp";
CreateTexture(g_Texture, L"building1.bmp", 0);
CreateTexture(g_Texture, L"clock.bmp", 0);
```

or

**Don't change your function prototype, but call the `A` version of the API function:**

```
pBitmap = auxDIBImageLoadA(strFileName);
```

---

Recommended:  Stick to wide strings and use the correct string types.