# Convert LPSTR to LPCWSTR c++

Tags: c++

LPSTR a = LPSTR("hello");
how to convert a to LPCWSTR?
string in C++ are confusing me, why methods use LPCWSTR and not just LPSTR D:
I hope someone can provide a link where I can learn C++ strings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert from LPCSTR to LPCWSTR in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044506/how-to-convert-from-lpcstr-to-lpcwstr-in-c)

Comment: i will check that link out

Comment: @Renat _lpa is undefined

Comment: On Windows, LPSTR is char*, LPCWSTR is wchar_t*. Answer here: [How to convert char* to wchar_t*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032080/how-to-convert-char-to-wchar-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPSTR` and `LPCWSTR` are Windows specific types. They are not c++ strings, but char pointers alias which are C.

The STL - Standard Template Library - which is shipped with C++ provides a `std::string` class, which is a convinient alias for `basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`. See the [documentation here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: this is too hard :(

Comment: @Crazy Simon https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdstring/

Comment: @CrazySimon `std::string my_str = "hello, world";` not that hard ?

Comment: yes but this... `basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`

Comment: @CrazySimon That's because the STL support different kinds of strings, i.e. plain ASCII bytes and wide characters for Unicode. `basic_string` is a template that gets instantiated with types that describe the kind of character. But this is not relevant for a beginner; you can just use `std::string`.