# Error: argument of type "cons char *" is incompatible with parameters of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: visual-c++

I am writing a code in Visual C++ to access serial port of a computer.

Code is given below:-

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef __CAPSTONE_CROSS_SERIAL_PORT__ 
#define __CAPSTONE_CROSS_SERIAL_PORT__
HANDLE hSerial= CreateFile("COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
```

In the above code I am getting an error at ""COM1"" in last line of above code.

Error is given below:-

```
Error: argument of type "cons char *" is incompatible with parameters of type "LPCWSTR"
```

I want to know why I am getting this error and who to resolve it.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230758/what-does-lpcwstr-stand-for-and-how-should-it-be-
handled-with