# LPCWSTR Error - C++

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I'm trying to draw text to a window. Some enough, two things I'm wondering. Why can the tutorial I'm using not put an L"String Here" and I have to?

I'm confused about that, anyway back to the main point, I;m trying to draw text and I'm getting an error.

[image]

Comment: Because you have `UNICODE` defined, as should be.

Comment: @chris is LPCWSTR dependent on UNICODE being defined?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, No, but the type of the parameter is. It would be a `LPCSTR` without.

Comment: How would I fix this?

Comment: @chris ah true, missed that.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `TextOut()` maps to either `TextOutA()` or `TextOutW()` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined.  In this case, it is defined, so `TextOutW()` is being called, and it expects `LPCWSTR` (ie `const wchar_t*`) as input, but a `const char*` from `std::string::c_str()` is being passed to it instead, hense the error.

Comment: @Jordan, Use `std::wstring`.

Comment: @chris but then it wouldn't compile without UNICODE. He can use TCHAR* or TextOut (if it works, dunno)

Comment: @Jordan: or use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`

Comment: try std::wstring s = "Hello, World!";  ... oops repeat response.

Comment: Fixed thanks guys. Why do I have to do that, and the book I'm learning from doesn't? Is it just the compiler?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, I prefer it that way. `std::to_wstring` and everything still work, and supporting ANSI shouldn't be a requirement anymore.

Comment: @Jordan: the book is likely assuming that `UNICODE` is not being defined.

Comment: And what is this "Unicode"?

Comment: -1:  Please don't post *images* of code and error messages -- post the actual code and the actual error message *as formatted text*.

Comment: No need to be rude about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have UNICODE defined in your project (which you should be default) then you can either use

> wstring s = L"Hello, World!";

or the ANSI API for TextOut

> TextOutA(hdc, 10, 10, s.c_str(), s.size());

Answer (score 1):

See the following question:

[What does LPCWSTR stand for and how should it be handled with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230758/what-does-lpcwstr-stand-for-and-how-should-it-be-handled-with)

Basically, you're trying to convert a regular character string to a wide character string implicitly and it won't allow you to do that. From the top answer:

> To get a normal C literal string to assign to a LPCWSTR, you need to prefix it with L
>
> LPCWSTR a = L"TestWindow";