# Xbox constrain error E0302

Tags: javascript, html, xbox-one

I'm devoloping an app for xbox one javascript/html5.
I try to constrain the app by console with this command.

```
c:\>xbapp constrain <package_name>
```

I get this error

```
E0302 - The requested operation is not valid for this package type.
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [downloaded the documentation<sup>1</sup>](https://twitter.com/notHALT/status/550076554530013185) and searched for Constrain. You lack sufficient details in your question. Make sure that you are using the ***fully-qualified*** package name in your command. Also, what does your package name look like in the command line? The documentation below should help you out.

Here is what I found:

## Command line

> ## xbapp constrain
>
> Displays a dialog box and places the specified title into constrained mode for testing.
>   For more information application states, see Application Model: Overview.
>
> ```
> xbapp constrain [/X[:]address[+<accesskey>]] package_full_name
> ```
>
> ### Options:
>
> #### `/X[:]address[+<accesskey>]`
>
> Specifies the host name or address (shown as Tools IP on the console) of a targeted console, but does not change the default console. For information about setting a host name for a console, see Setting a Hostname for the Console IP Address.
>
> If you do not use this option, the default console (previously set by Connect (xbconnect.exe)) is used.
>
> Accesskey is a string that you can use to restrict access to a console to only those people who know the access key. Set the access key by using the command xbconfig accesskey=your-key; then, restart your console to make the access key effective.
>
> To access a console that is configured with an access key, you must include a plus sign (+) and the access key after the IP address or host name of the console. For more information about access keys, see xbconfig accesskey.
>
> **Note**: If an access key is provided when the default console is set by xbconnect, then the access key is stored as part of the address of the default console.
>
> #### `package_full_name`
>
> Specifies the full package name of the application. For example, `mygame_1.0.0.0_neutral__r9wapr0zzdgy`.
>
> **Note**: The full package name is displayed when a package is deployed using Visual Studio or the command xbapp deploy. A complete list of full package names and AUMIDs for the registered applications on a development kit can be obtained using the command xbapp list.

## C++ class method

> Places the app with the specified package monitor into constrained mode.
>
> ## Syntax
>
> **C++**
>
> ```
> public:
> HRESULT Constrain(
>     LPCWSTR pszPackageMoniker
> )
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> *`pszPackageMoniker`*
>       Type: *`LPCWSTR`*
>       Pointer to the package moniker of the app to put into constrained mode.
>
> ### Return value
>
> Type: `HRESULT`
>   `HRESULT` *success* or error code.

## Notes

**`LPCWSTR`** stands for: *Long Pointer to Constant Wide String* [More info<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230778/1762224)