# Visual Studio 2010 Arduino cpp Error: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arduino, tchar, lpcwstr

I'm trying to set up an arduino uno for serial port communication with a C++ program in visual studio 2010. I'm working from the code found here: http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

Unfortunately, the .cpp file gives me the following message for line 9 for the variable 'portName':

Error: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

I don't understand this error message, and have tried a few different things to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does LPCWSTR stand for and how should it be handled with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230758/what-does-lpcwstr-stand-for-and-how-should-it-be-handled-with)

Answer (score 11):

Given the code link in your question, it seems the problem is here:

> ```
> Serial::Serial(char *portName)
> {
>     ...
>
>     this->hSerial = CreateFile(portName,  // <--- ERROR
> ```

[`CreateFile` is a Win32 API that expects an `LPCTSTR` as first string parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) .

`LPCTSTR` is a Win32 typedef, which is expanded to:

- `const char*` in ANSI/MBCS builds
- `const wchar_t*` in Unicode builds (which have been the default since VS2005)

Since you are using VS2010, probably you are in the default Unicode build mode.

Actually, there is no "physical" `CreateFile` API exposed, but there are two distinct functions: `CreateFileA` and `CreateFileW`. The former takes a `const char*` input string, the latter takes a `const wchar_t*`.

In Unicode builds, `CreateFile` is a preprocessor macro expanded to `CreateFileW`; in ANSI/MBCS builds, `CreateFile` is expanded to `CreateFileA`.

So, if you are in Unicode build mode, your CreateFile call is expanded to `CreateFileW(const wchar_t*, ...)`. Since `portName` is defined as a `char*`, there is a mismatch between `wchar_t*` and `char*`, and you get a compiler error.

To fix that, you have some options.

For example, you could be explicit in your code, and just call **`CreateFileA()`** instead of `CreateFile()`. In this way, you will be using the ANSI/MBCS version of the function (i.e., the one taking a `const char*`), independently from the actual ANSI/MBCS/Unicode settings in Visual Studio.

---

Another option would be to change your current build settings from the default Unicode mode to ANSI/MBCS. To do that, you can follow the path:

```
Project Properties | Configuration Properties | General | Character Set
```

and select **"Use Multi-Byte Character Set"**, as showed in the following screenshot:

[image: Setting Multi-Byte Character Set in VS2010 IDE]

Comment: Your answer in definitely more useful for beginners than mine, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning CreateFileA and CreateFileW.  I didn't even know about them.

Answer (score 2):

Your settings in Visual Studio are probably set to Unicode but the code you're compiling expects ASCII.

Go to Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Character Set and choose "Use Multi-Byte Character Set".

-Surenthar

Answer (score 1):

Your settings in Visual Studio are probably set to Unicode but the code you're compiling expects ASCII.

Go to Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Character Set and choose "Use Multi-Byte Character Set".

You should also remove `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` from C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor definitions, if they are defined there.

This will make your code call the ASCII versions of the Windows API functions, which accept `char` strings.

Comment: AND constant. LPCWSTR means "long pointer to constant wide string". A `wchar_t const *`.

Comment: The string is marked `const` because `CreateFile` doesn't change it, but you can still pass a non-const pointer.