# Using std::filesystem output as LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, wininet

I'm making a program which recursively lists all files in a certain directory and uploads each file separately to an FTP server using WinINet.
The problem I'm encountering is using filesystem::path::filename in the FtpPutFile() function because a LPCWSTR is needed.
Whats the best and easiest way to convert it (or somehow use it as is)?

```
    std::string path = "C:\\Programs";
    for (const auto & entry : std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
        FtpPutFile(hIConnect, entry.path().filename(), entry.path().filename(), FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
```

The error I get is:
no suitable conversion function from "const std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path" to "LPCWSTR" exists

EDIT: Here is a solution that worked for me, by following Lightness solution:

```
    std::string path = "C:\\Programs";
    for (const auto & entry : std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
        FtpPutFile(hIConnect, entry.path().wstring().c_str(), entry.path().filename().wstring().c_str(), FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`LPCWSTR` is Microsoft's obfuscation of the `const wchar_t*` type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230888/560648), and [`filesystem` paths conveniently have a `wstring()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string). As you may recall, C++ strings give you access to their character buffer, too, via `c_str()`.

So, `entry.path().filename().wstring().c_str()` is a `LPCWSTR` you can use (ugh!). Be careful to use that immediately, or store the result of `wstring()` somewhere for as long as you need the `LPCWSTR` to survive, because `wstring()` returns by value and you don't want a dangling pointer.

```
// Untested, but a logical adaptation of your code
const std::string path = "C:\\Programs";
std::experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator it(path);
for (const auto& entry : it)
{
    const std::wstring filename = entry.path().filename().wstring();

    FtpPutFile(
       hIConnect,
       filename.c_str(),
       filename.c_str(),
       FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY,
       0
    );
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! But do you mind explaining about the "be careful" part?

Comment: @Apex Sure - added