# Same code in two projects, but one doesn't work, C++

Tags: c++

Im following a YouTube video that explains how to create a simple game with C++, here is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD0WzbKJcOg&list=PL7Ej6SUky135IAAR3PFCFyiVwanauRqj3&index=2&ab_channel=DanZaidan
He is using Visual Studio 2019, im using 2022 but i dont think that's a problem. I literally copied and pasted in my project the same code he published under the video after many attempts, but it still doesn't work even if it's the same. If i leave the code in his project, it works, if i copy and paste it inside my project, it doesn't. Here are the two differences i noticed:
1- The external dependencies folder of my project has different files than his.
2- In my project, the IDE tells me that there are two mistakes.
Sorry if its a noob question, im really new in programming.

[image]

```
#include <windows.h>

bool running = true;

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    LRESULT result = 0;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        running = false;
    } break;

    default: {
        result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    }
    return result;
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    // Create Window Class
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = "Game Window Class";  \\GIVES ME ERROR***********
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;

    // Register Class
    RegisterClass(&window_class);

    // Create Window (GIVES ME ERROR)*****************************
    HWND window = CreateWindow(window_class.lpszClassName, "My First Game!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    while (running) {
        // Input
        MSG message;
        while (PeekMessage(&message, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }

        // Simulate

        // Render
    }

}
```

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language.  There's no such language as "C/C++".  Which one is it?

Comment: Hope this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230758/what-does-lpcwstr-stand-for-and-how-should-it-be-handled-with

Comment: your project is configured for unicode, his isn't. A key skill for the modern C++ programmer is the ability to copy and paste obscure error messages into google or stackoverflow where someone else will have had the exact same problem as you before

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: @AlanBirtles so what am i supposed to do? Is it possible to deactivate it to follow his project?

Comment: see the linked duplicates, there are exact instructions